# TCP *:hbci (LISTEN) - What does hbci mean?

Tags: linux, tcp, netstat

I simply open an http server from my terminal (with node) listening on port 3000, which is obviously working if I request localhost:3000 in a browser.

Now, I want to see this connection so I use `netstat`.
I'm supposed to see server connection on port 3000, and client connection on another port:

```
$ netstat -p tcp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state) 
tcp6       0      0  localhost.hbci         localhost.50215        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.50215        localhost.hbci         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.hbci         localhost.50214        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.50214        localhost.hbci         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.hbci         localhost.50213        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.50213        localhost.hbci         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.hbci         localhost.50211        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.hbci         localhost.50212        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.50212        localhost.hbci         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.50211        localhost.hbci         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.hbci         localhost.50210        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  localhost.50210        localhost.hbci         ESTABLISHED
```

No entries about the server connection on port 3000. But the localhost.hbci, switching from a local to a foreign address, seems to be my server connection.
And if I type:

```
$ lsof -i TCP:3000
COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE             SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
node    1144 garysounigo   11u  IPv6 0x6d9a12e1e288efc7 0t0       TCP  *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

I'm sure that hbci represent my port 3000.

Does anyone know something about what hbci means or refers to?
Is it a port for local server ? A protocol for s local connection?
I find anythings everywhere (  on any port.. ;) )

Comment: Note `netstat` by default does not display TCP (including TCP6) sockets in LISTEN state; to see them add `-a` to any version, or `-l` (ell) to the version usually used on Linux as your tags say but I believe not OSX as your text says. (`lsof` does include LISTEN, as you see.)

Comment: Related:   [Is the same port acting as both client and server?](https://superuser.com/q/683965/354511)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does anyone know what hbci means or refers to?

HBCI stands for "Home Banking Computer Interface", see http://openhbci.sourceforge.net/. The same port number is also used by the "`RemoteWare Client`", at least according to http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/ports03000.htm.

The reason you are seeing it is because `netstat` and similar utilities look up port numbers in a database that maps them to symbolic names (usually, `/etc/services`).

To suppress this behavior in `netstat`, one can pass the `--numeric-ports` option, or just `-n` which also makes some other things numeric.

Comment: Amaaazing .. You are right !! Actually I think -- option are not available in OSX and dont find the equivalent - for numeric ports option for netstats in OSX.   BUUUT for lsof its juts -P so with ``lsof -P -i TCP:3000`` you gave me    ``TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)``

Comment: One last, do you the meaning difference between ``*:3000`` and ``localhost:3000``

Comment: More canonically: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Comment: @G;S: `*:port` is usable only for LISTEN state and means accept connections on any address and thus any interface. `localhost:port` or `127.0.0.1:port` or `::1:port` or possibly `[::1]:port` in LISTEN means accept on the loopback address/interface only but in other states simply means that connection is using the loopback address/interface. See `man ip`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot; im a newbie but already see the lo network interface. This interface is used to intern service connections if i remember well